# how to access local storage using pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads, local-storage

I have code that is completely parallel, no dependencies, so using pthreads was a natural choice.  Unfortunately, there is one shared resource, the log file.

We don't want the log to be interleaved line-by-line in any case, so rather than use mutexes on every log call I want to open a separate log file for each thread.  But currently, all through the code, there is a global variable logger.

I currently have two solutions, neither of which makes me happy.

1. Implement a hash on the thread id: pthread_self().
2. Pass the parameter from the thread creation to every function it calls (very invasive).

I'd love some clever way to make it look like I have a global variable in each thread, something with very little overhead.

Comment: please add a code example of how you're currently using this variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each thread gets its own log, use pthread_key_create and related functions to maintain a per-thread logger variable.

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard way to handle such per-thread variables: `pthread_key_create` and company.

If you are just happy with gcc and its extensions, they have the `__thread` keyword for per thread storage.

Answer (score 2):

**Good fix**: don't use the global variable anymore, and have each thread have its own logging object.

**Quick fix**: transform your logger global variable into a macro that expands into the logging function call, passing the thread ID. Or, use pthreads own local-to-thread storing capabilities (see pthread keys).

So, let's say you have:

```
log(global_fd, char* entry);
```

You can avoid having to modify every time that happens via:

```
#define global_fd get_thread_fd()
```

And voilà!

Comment: Doing it like this would allow you to access `logger_fd` as if it were a normal variable: `#define logger_fd (*(int *)pthread_getspecific(logger_key))` but of course it involves some extra indirection.